# What thread will be used when calling subscribeOn inside flatMapCompletable?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a completable that I create like so:

```
public class Params {
    // Contains input parameters
}

public Completable startSomething(Params params) {
    return Completable
        .fromRunnable(() -> someMainThreadThing(params))
        .subscribeOn(this.schedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Now, I have a source providing a `Single<Params>`. This is provided as part of the API, so the current thread is unknown at subscribe time. This usage looks something like this:

```
public Completable doSomethingWithParams(Single<Params> params) {
    // Do something with the params
}
```

I would like to implement `doSomethingWithParams` like so:

```
public Completable doSomethingWithParams(Single<Params> params) {
    return params.flatMapCompletable(::startSomething);
}
```

My question is, is `someMainThreadThing` guaranteed to be executed on the main thread, or can the setup of the `Single<Params>` influence the thread it is executed on?

Comment: Yes, this setup guarantees `someMainThreadThing` runs on the main thread and completes there too because of `subscribeOn` applied to the inner `Completable`.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [`Single.flatMapCompletable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMapCompletable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-)

> flatMapCompletable does not operate by default on a particular Scheduler.

That means that `completable` with `startSomething()` will be invoked on the same scheduler (thread) as previous chain actions if you don't call explicitly switching between schedulers.

To switch between schedulers you can use `observeOn()` operator. In your case reactive chain could look like

```
Single.fromCallable(getParams())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(this.schedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMapCompletable(::startSomething)
```

In that case `subscribeOn()` make executing `getParams()` on `Schedulers.io()`, after that `observeOn()` switches to main thread and execute `startSomething()` on it.